# css files are sent as html/text by http.FileServer in net/http package

Tags: html, css, go

Following is a simple web server serving html file using http.FileServer method. The css file is sent as text/html and browser complains and does not use the css.

```
package main
import (
    "net/http"
)
func main() {

mux := http.NewServeMux()
setupRoutes(mux)
srv := &http.Server{
    Addr:         "127.0.0.1:9090",
    Handler: mux,
}

if err := srv.ListenAndServe(); err != http.ErrServerClosed {
    println(err.Error())
    return
}
   println("Server starting on port,", "127.0.0.1:9090")

}

func setupRoutes(router *http.ServeMux){

    router.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("../web")))
}
```

And html file is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>test</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../web/global.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p> Test line</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

And global.css file is as follows:

```
p {
  color: red
}
```

Run the server and enter http://localhost:9090/ in the browser. The developer console in the browser reports the following error:

```
localhost/:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:9090/web/global.css' because its 
MIME type ('text/plain') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking 
is enabled.
```

The project directory structure is as follows:

```
go
  src
     main 
        main.go
     web
        index.html
        global.css
```

Environment is: macOS 10.15.7;  go version go1.15.3 darwin/amd64;
Google Chrome - Version 86.0.4240.111 (Official Build) (x86_64)

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Check the contents of the file in the browser's console, my guess it's not finding the file and the response is actually a 404 html page, or something like that. If that's the case you need to make sure your http.Dir is accurate and actually has access to the file, then you need to make sure your `href` is accurate and actually sends a request to the correct location which is served by the http.FileServer.

Comment: Instead of browser console you can check with curl: `curl http://localhost:9090/web/global.css`, do you get the css or 404?

Comment: And please do not use relative paths. This won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your project directory structure as below.

```
go
   src 
      main.go
      web
          index.html
          global.css
```

And change html file as below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/global.css">
</head>
<body>
    <p> Test line</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And change main.go setupRoutes function as below.

```
func setupRoutes(router *http.ServeMux) {
    router.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./web")))
}
```